# Forwarding AWS EC2 Instance Requests to Docker API

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-network

My setup is a docker container with a node app running on port 3000 ran using

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 <IMAGE> node dist/src/main.js
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-192:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS
da3fdeb2b843   image   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 minutes ago   Up 18 minutes   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp
```

From inside EC2 netstat,

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:3000               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

My EC2 Instance has public access.
[AWS Security Group Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FgIS.png)

When I SSH into my EC2 container I can run curl localhost:3000/status and see a response from node app.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-8-192:~$ curl localhost:3000/status
{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /status","error":"Not Found"}
```

Unfortunately, from my local terminal curl {EC2-Public IPv4 DNS}:3000/status times out, verbose output

```
Jamess-MBP-2:~ jamesspaniak$ curl -v <EC2-Public IPv4 DNS>:3000/status
*   Trying <EC2-Public IPv4>:3000...
* connect to <EC2-Public IPv4> port 3000 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to <EC2-Public IPv4 DNS> port 3000 after 75008 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to <EC2-Public IPv4 DNS> port 3000 after 75008 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I've also tried opening all ports and using port 80 with docker run -p 80:3000 but same result.

I've also added an inbound rule to allow ICMP Echo Request and can successfully ping my public IP.

What other things can I look at to resolve this? I expected to be able to make a request to the running docker container from outside the EC2 instance. Apreciated.

Comment: What does a `netstat -a | grep 3000` return when you're logged into the server via ssh?  My guess is that it is only listening on the localhost/127.0.0.1 address.

Comment: I added the netstat output to answer since that is relevant as well. It does appear to be 0.0.0.0 though.

Comment: Based on another answer I updated my listening host to be as follows
```
await app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
```

Still can see inside ec2 but not from my machine. All answers are pointing to security group not being setup but i expect it to be allowing all inbound traffic.